# How to create and integrate getDatabyID in junit

Tags: java, junit

I have code like this

```
@Test
    void showDataById() throws Exception {
        Optional<ProductParameterTable> data = service.getByUuid(this.ppr.getProductParameterTableId());
        ProductParameterTable pp = new ProductParameterTable();
        pp.setProductParameterTableId(data.get().getProductParameterTableId());


        when(service.getByUuid(any(String.class))).thenReturn(data);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/product/{uuid}", pp.getProductParameterTableId())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$..product_parameter_table_id").value(pp.getProductParameterTableId()));

        verify(service, VerificationModeFactory.times(1)).getByUuid(Mockito.any());
        reset(service);
    }
```

but when I check in my intellij this code not coverage my controller. before I create this code I have code for insert. that code for insert is coverage. but for this code not coverage. I use gradle 6.7

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test FAILED
> Task :jacocoTestReport SKIPPED
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':test'.

> No tests found for given includes: jii..controller.product.ProductParameterTableControllerTest

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD FAILED in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date

so how to fix my problem for this code ?